# Failed saving metadata to metadataCache

Tags: linux, zend-framework, memcached

I did a lot digging around for a solution to this problem and was unable to come to a solution.

**Problem:**
I have a Zend Framework 1.10.7 application running on the terminal and through a web interface. When it is running over the web it works flawlessly but when I run it through command line it keeps giving me an error

> Notice: Failed saving metadata to metadataCache

I looked at various other topics including [Accessing the Zend Application Bootstrap _init Functions After Bootstrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331081/accessing-the-zend-application-bootstrap-init-functions-after-bootstrapping) and I was still unable to solve the problem because I really couldn't follow what was going on there. It seems to be the same problem but I just couldn't understand what to do.

Could someone please help me out with this?

Here is the basic of what I have:

**Bootstrap**

```
protected function _initRouter()
{
    if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli') {
        $this->bootstrap('frontcontroller');
        $front = $this->getResource('frontcontroller');
        $front->setRouter(new PP_Tasks_Init());
        //$front->setRequest(new Zend_Controller_Request_Simple());
    }
}
```

Comment: The `PP_Tasks_Init()` is actually a router that entends `Zend_Controller_Router_Abstract`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the user of the command line and web have the right permissions to access the `Zend_Cache` backend.

I would run the command line application under same user like your web application or
try do change the settings of `Zend_Cache`-backend and the underlying application.
You find more information about `Zend_Cache_Backend` [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.backends.html).

Answer (score 0):

In you php.ini file please enable APC for cli mode as well,

Not very sure about the variable but it would be like as below

apc-cli-enable = 1

Also don't forget to restart the Apache to see changes

Answer (score 0):

To me. This problem occurred because there was not enough space on the server.