# How fix error "Failed saving metadata to metadataCache" with Memcached backend?

Tags: zend-framework, memcached, zend-cache

I have application on Zend Framework 1.6 and I use Memcached as backend cache. When I restart Memcached I get error message "Failed saving metadata to metadataCache". Please advice how can I solve this problem.

In my memcached.conf i wrote setting -u www-data

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840522/failed-saving-metadata-to-metadatacache or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331081/accessing-the-zend-application-bootstrap-init-functions-after-bootstrapping help at all?